# Calculate $I_{m, n}=\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^{m}(x)\, \sin^{n}(x) \, dx,$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions

Does anyone have a reference which gives the explicit expression of the following  integral

$$I_{m, n}=\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^{m}(x)\,  \sin^{n}(x) \,  dx,$$
for any positive integers $m,n.$

Thank you you in advance?

Comment: If $m$ is odd, it's zero. If $m$ is even, it's twice the integral on $[0,\pi/2]$ which is a Beta integral.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much @Lord Shark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lord Shark the Unknown noted, for even $m$ we have $$I_{m,\,n}=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m x\sin^n x\,dx=\operatorname{B}\bigg(\frac{m+1}{2},\,\frac{n+1}{2}\bigg).$$

Comment: @ J. G. we have the same for $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{m}(x)\,  \sin^{n}(x) \,  dx$ ?

Comment: @Z.Alfata If you consider the shape of $\cos x$, you'll see why the result is $2I_{m,\,n}$.